# Spring Tool Suite 3.7.0 not reading @ConfigurationProperties for content assist in YML

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-tool-suite

Hi I have move on to spring tool suite 3.7.0 with the highly anticipated feature of YAML editor as described here https://spring.io/blog/2015/06/30/spring-tool-suite-3-7-0-released specially the content assist that it provides .
The issue I am having is that my properties class as below

```
 @ConfigurationProperties(prefix="datasource.ucp")
    @Data
    public Class DumbProperties{
    private String url;
    private String user;
    ...
    }
```

does work but when I open my application.yml I still have to provide these manually the content assist doesnt work .ALso STS givem me a warning that the property doesnt exists .Screen shot below

[image]

ALso the maven entry for the same to find @ConfigurationProperties are added as below

```
<dependency>
<groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
<optional>true</optional>
```

anything I am missing here!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things have to be in place for the configuration properties in your own source-code to work.

1. The "spring-boot-configuration-processor" must be on the classpath
2. The project must be confgure properly so that Eclipse JDT Annotation Processing is enabled to run the spring-boot-configuration-processor as part of an eclipse workspace build.

It sounds like you have 1. so probably its number 2. that's missing.

Normally, 2. should be configured automatically by STS, but it does this as part of m2e project configuration. If you just added the configuration-processor by pasting the xml into your pom, then its likely the project-configurator has not yet been executed. So try forcing it by selecting "Update Project" from the "Maven" context menu (accessed by right click on your project).

If that doesn't help, we'll have to troubleshoot a bit more as I don't know what's missing from your project's setup.

Comment: you made my day that worked excellent advice ..Thanks a lot .Hope spring adds that to the docs also somewhere as FAQ's or something

Comment: I tried to make it a 'no brainer' by implementing a 'quickfix' that you can apply from the 'warning' you see when you start using @ConfigurationProperties in your code.

Comment: ... When you use the quickfix it modifies the pom for you and also makes sure to execute the project configurator. Unfortunately when you manually paste dependency xml ... m2e adds the jar to your classpath but doesn't bother re-executing project configurators (because in most cases it would not be needed. This is a case that should be pretty rare (and it would fix itself eventually).

Comment: Yup it did warn unfortunately at that time I posted the maven every rather than applying the suggested quick fix. Anyways thanks for your insights